# Insert embeded number in a vector matlab

Tags: matlab

Hey everyone I would like to do the following. I have a vector f.e. [1 2 3 4 6 8] and I want to end up in that vector [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] but generally, not like [v(1:4) 5 v(6) 7 v(8)]. 
Thank you very much!!

Comment: So `interp1` then?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, could you explain please? Thank you!

Comment: I'll let the documentation explain it for me: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

Comment: I was thinking something like this [1 2 3 4 6 8] and [0 0 0 0 5 0 7 0]. And try to concatenate them in the second vector.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Can you rather give the actual application that you're after?

Comment: From the little information you give, `v(1):v(end)` would do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is too vague, I'm not sure that I understand correctly, but this is what I came up with

If you have array to be modified

```
a = [a_1, ..., a_n]
```

and you want to insert

```
b = [b_1, ..., b_m]
```

and the position you want to insert

```
b_pos = [p_1, ..., p_m]
```

Then

```
n = length(a);
m = length(b);

a_pos = setdiff(1:(n+m),b_pos) % find index which is not included in b_pos

c = zeros(1,n+m);
c(a_pos) = a;
c(b_pos) = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know your vector is going to be sorted you can use:
    `a = [1 2 3 4 6 8];` then 
    `a = sort([a,5,7]);`
This appends the additional values to the vector, sorts them, and assigns the sorted vector to the original variable.

Comment: Νο, I don't know it. Let me tell you exactly how it goes.I want it to be smthg like this
[0 10 14 7 8 9 10]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
and the final
[0 10 14 7 0 8 9 0 10]

Comment: Perhaps those arrays didn't come out as intended, but it doesn't appear that there is a way to programmatically determine where you wanted those zeros inserted in the array without further specification.

Comment: Ι have an auxiliary vector n, which contains the positions the zeros must take...For this example the n would be n=[5 8]... Does that help?

Comment: Sure, but I don't think you're going to find a pre-defined function for it. I think you're going to need a custom function with three inputs (array1[], values2insert[], positions2insertat[]) and append to the segments based on the positions2insertat[]. Does that help you?

Comment: Ofc, that's what I was thinking, the point is that I don't want to replace an existing number of the vector with a new value, instead I want to enter a new value to the vector...I'm not being clear right? I'm sorry guys!

Comment: @DimitrisBoukosis Okay, I think I get what you're saying now. Could you add that bit about the auxiliary vector to your question? It seems to me that it's rather critical to the solution.

Comment: @DimitrisBoukosis, try this: `temp=[];    t=1;     for x=1:length { (values2insert) temp=[temp,array1(t:positions2insertat(x-1)),values2insert(x)];     t=positions2insertat(x); }`    This may have issues and will probably fail if you insert a value at index=1 (add additional case), but it should be pretty close. I apologize: I don't have Matlab installed on my machine right now.